# How exactly condition like someItem?.someField==somevalue are evaluated in angular?

Tags: angular

So lets have simple condition in markup:

`someItem?.someField==somevalue`

What is going on here? Is is equally to

`someItem!=null && someItem!=nudefined && someItem==somevalue`

So basicly whole condition short circuits to `false` if `someItem` is undefined? Is it angular specific syntax or is it javascript feature?

Comment: It's javascript and yes, if someItem is falsy than the condition is false, otherwise it compares the someFiled value with someValue and returns the result.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/compiler_util/expression_converter.ts#L437-L557

Comment: It's converted like `((someItem == null) ? null : someItem.someField) == somevalue`

Comment: @yurzui are you sure? someItem? works fine with undefined as well while undefined<>null

Comment: I'm sure. btw `null == undefined` but `null !== undefined`

Comment: Open this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1u4l2?file=app%2Fapp.component.html and also open devtool. You will see something like this http://take.ms/G5RuQ

Answer (score 0):

Safe navigation operator `?.` (also known as the `Elvis Operator`) is an angular 2 template expression operator.

Safe navigation operator avoids exception for null and undefined values in property paths.

While accessing properties from object it may throw exception if object is null or undefined.

For safer side we can use safe navigation operator to access property from object and hence it will not throw exception for the scenario that object is null or undefined.

It can also be used in case of complex objects - e.g. `{{foo?.bar?.bas}}`.

However, in case of arrays, normal null check strategy should be used e.g.`{{records && records[0]}}`.

---

JavaScript code fails to read this operator

```js
let x = {
  y: 12
};

try {
  if (x ? .y > 10) {
    console.log('it works!');
  }
} catch (ex) {
  console.log('exception');
}
```

---

References -

1. [concretepage.com](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-pipe-operator-and-safe-navigation-operator-example#safe-navigation-operator)
2. [c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-safe-navigation-operator-in-angular-2/)

Comment: This does not quite ansswer my question. Please notice that I am not asking about elvis operator per se, but rather what is going on later on - eg. when results is to be compared.

Comment: I think second line answers your question.  Under the hood, ` the operator returns value of the object path if it exists, else it returns the null value`. Please go through the reference links for all the examples.